# social-share-button gem not having default message for Facebook and Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, socialshare

I'm using https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button for my [website](http://www.collegeinsideview.com/) (scroll down to see).

When you click the Twitter icon, it has the default post "College reviews are too broad. Please help answer some more specific questions about your school!". However, it isn't appearing when you click the Facebook and Google+ icons.

Why is this? Here's my code: `<p><%= social_share_button_tag('College reviews are too broad. Please help answer some more specific questions about your school!') %></p>`.